# Incorrect link parameter on the "Complex Queries" documentation page

Tags: bug, documentation, api-v2.1

[The "Complex Queries" documentation page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/min-max) has this link:

> Of [these](https://serverfault.com/questions/3743/what-useful-things-can-one-add-to-ones-bashrc) [three](https://serverfault.com/questions/327738/how-dangerous-is-a-wet-server-room-floor) [posts](https://serverfault.com/questions/339426/10-servers-to-administer-and-im-a-history-major) on Server Fault, [the one with the most recent activity](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids#page=1&pagesize=1&order=desc&sort=activity&ids=3743%3B327738%3B339426&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

where "*the one with the most recent activity*" links to

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids#page=1&pagesize=1&order=desc&sort=activity&ids=3743%3B327738%3B339426&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true
```

The query string parameter `site=stackoverflow` should be `site=serverfault`.

Comment: Also, that page's URL is `https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/min-max`. What does "min-max" have to do with "Complex Queries"? ... The page URL should be corrected and a 301 redirect placed on the old URL.